# TO_CHAR and TO_DATE use and the right context to use them

Tags: sql, oracle

If I have a query like:

```
select *
from CAT_ACCT_AUDIT_TRAIL cataccount0_
where cataccount0_.CAAT_EXECUTED_DATE >=TO_DATE(’26-AUG-2016′, ‘DD-MM-YYYY’) AND
       to_Date(TO_CHAR(cataccount0_.CAAT_EXECUTED_DATE , ‘dd -mon-yyyy’), ‘DD-MM-YYYY’)<=TO_DATE('31-AUG-2016', 'DD-MM-YYYY')
```

Here why do we require the `to_char` or `to_date` functions? What is the right context to use them?

If I do either of these:

```
select TO_DATE('26-AUG-2016', 'DD-MM-YYYY') from dual;
select TO_DATE('01-12-2016', 'DD-MM-YYYY') from dual;
```

I get the output in NLS variable format as I set in the session, irrespective of date input in format conversion; I get the same result for both. Wy is this so?

What is the correct way to solve this query? I mean when i need to fetch the values in date range.

Comment: Your sample has "typographic" single quotes (back quote and forward quote) mixed in with "straight" single quotes. `‘’` vs. `'`. In Oracle, don't **ever** use anything but "straight" quotes in your code (except in string literals), and pay attention if your editor, like MS Word, changes them to something else.

Comment: Why -4 ?, I have provided all details which are needed and asked the question right to the point ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You use [`to_date()`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions219.htm#SQLRF06132) to convert a string like `'01-12-2016'` to the date datatype. You use [`to_char()`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions216.htm#SQLRF06129) to convert a date to a string. In both cases you specify the [format](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00212) of the string - if you don't then your session NLS settings are used, which is not good practice for anything except ad hoc queries as someone else running your code later may get a different output or an error.

A general rule - which your code is following - is to compare data of one type with values/constants of the same type. As your column is a date, you're supplying the filter values as dates - by converting strings to the date datatype. If you didn't do that then implicit conversion would happen, but you should not rely on that either as it can also lead to NLS issues, and depending on the type it can prevent indexes being used. [Read more about data conversion in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements002.htm#SQLRF00214).

Oracle tries to be flexible when interpreting the string when you do `to_date()`. When you do `TO_DATE('26-AUG-2016', 'DD-MM-YYYY')` you are supplying the month as a string (in a specific language, which is another topic), but telling the function to expect a number. Oracle 'helpfully' interprets that anyway, so it usually works. But whatever format you use for `to_date()`, you aren't specifying the display format, so your client is deciding how to display the converted date as a string for you - usually using your NLS settings, again.

Doing this:

```
to_Date(TO_CHAR(cataccount0_.CAAT_EXECUTED_DATE , ‘dd -mon-yyyy’), ‘DD-MM-YYYY’)
```

is usually pointless, but even so should be using consistent format models. One reason this is sometimes done is if the source date (`caat_executed_date` here) has its time set to something other than midnight, and you want to discard the time. But there are better ways to do that - specifically the [`trunc()`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions236.htm#SQLRF06151) function, which by default sets the time to midnight.

When you have constant values, like `TO_DATE('31-AUG-2016', 'DD-MM-YYYY')`, you can also use ANSI [date literals](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF51062), in the form of `DATE '2016-08-31'`.

Answer (score 5):

It is unclear what you want to do, but you don't actually need those functions on constants.  Just use the `date` keyword for date literals.  For instance:

```
where cataccount0_.CAAT_EXECUTED_DATE >= date '2016-08-26'
```

If you want to remove the time component from a date, then use `trunc()`:

```
where trunc(cataccount0_.CAAT_EXECUTED_DATE, 'dd')  -- the `'dd'` is optional for this purpose
```

This can be used in any context where a date constant is accepted.